# Getting syntax error while running access query please guide

Tags: ms-access, syntax-error

Hello Team I new to ACCESS, getting a syntax error for the below query

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is all the double quotation marks. Try this:

```
SELECT HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO, HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.SCH_B_CMDTY_CD, CAT_ID_HTSUSA_XREF.CAT_ID_NO_20, CAT_ID_HTSUSA_XREF.LAST_UPDT_TS, CAT_ID_HTSUSA_XREF.LAST_UPDT_LOGON_ID
 FROM   Z1TJ111$.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH HRMNZ_TRF_SCH INNER JOIN Z1TJ111$.CAT_ID_HTSUSA_XREF.CAT_ID_HTSUSA_XREF ON HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO=CAT_ID_HTSUSA_XREF.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO
 WHERE   NOT (HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='7211.23.3000' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8427.20.8000' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8427.90.0000' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8525.50.7010' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8525.60.1050' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8526.10.0040' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8526.91.0020' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8526.91.0040' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='8527.99.1500' OR HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO='9014.10.7080') AND HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.HRMNZ_TRF_SCH_NO<>HRMNZ_TRF_SCH.SCH_B_CMDTY_CD
```

Comment: still getting "Syntax Error From" so looks like something is missing within the "From" clause......

Comment: Set square brackets around field names that include a space . E. g. 
FROM   Z1TJ111$.[HRMNZ_TRF_SCH HRMNZ_TRF_SCH] should probably be
FROM   Z1TJ111$.[HRMNZ_TRF_SCH HRMNZ_TRF_SCH]

Comment: Thanks but still getting the same error syntax error from

Comment: Try square brackets around `Z1TJ111$` as well - Access may not like the $ symbol

Comment: should i put [] everywherer where it z1111$

Comment: Question edited now getting syntax error from clause

Answer (score 0):

Use the query editor to get tips about what is wrong. If you don't know how here is a tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_sql_view.htm

Comment: Please guide I am getting syntax error at clause I have pasted another code in question section

Comment: Paste your code in SQL view and show it in Design view. If you don't spot the error directly try remove a condition or a field and View then result. When it works you know where the error was.